# React Native - AppState with async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React Native, we use `AppState` to check app is in active or background or something. What I want to do is when appState eventListener is catch that app is going background, execute some async function.

But when that moment, non-async function is executed and async function is not executed and back to `foreGround(active)`, that async function is executed.

Maybe cause JavaScript Event Loop, that async function is buffered in a queue and executed in the foreground.

What could I do for executing instantly?

```js
const listener = AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
  let timeout;

  if (state === 'background') {
    asyncFunction();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `async` before function in listener and you could use await inside like:

```
const listener = AppState.addEventListener('change', async(state) => {
  let timeout;

  if (state === 'background') {
    await asyncFunction();
  }
})
```